# jquery toggle issue in firefox

Tags: php, jquery, slider, toggle

The below code works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work correctly in Firefox.

**In Chrome:**

Expanding the hide/show link shows the up arrow correctly when expanded and the down arrow when collapsed

**In Firefox:**

Expanding the hide/show link shows the up arrow correctly when expanded, but when collapsed it still shows the up arrow.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divView = $('div.view');
    var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass('view').height();
    $divView.addClass('view');      
    $('div.slide').click(function() {

        // Update the HTML in this element
        var slideHtml = $(this).html();

        // Switch between show/hide
        if (slideHtml.localeCompare('Hide / Show <img src="images/arrow_up.png" />') < 0)
           $(this).html('Hide / Show <img src="images/arrow_up.png" />');
        else
           $(this).html('Hide / Show <img src="images/arrow_down.png" />');
        $('div.view').animate({
          height: (($divView.height() == 90)? innerHeight  : "90px")
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div class="view">
   <ul>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="slide">Hide / Show <img src="images/arrow_down.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) it is much simpler and it avoids you all this.

I made you an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MVnbM/

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="clickMe">Click me</a>
<div class="arrowUp">Up</div>
<div class="arrowDown">Down</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.arrowUp').hide();
$('a.clickMe').click(function() {
   $('.arrowUp, .arrowDown').toggle(); 
});
```

Here's your code modified:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divView = $('div.view');
    var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass('view').height();
    $divView.addClass('view');      
    $('.arrowUp').hide();
    $('div.slide').click(function() {
        $('.arrowUp, .arrowDown').toggle(); 
    });
});

<div class="view">
   <ul>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
    <li>text here</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="slide">Hide / Show <img src="images/arrow_down.png" class="arrowUp" /><img src="images/arrow_down.png" class="arrowDown" /></div>
```

Comment: mmm... thanks, but that doesn't work - the link (when clicked) doesn't do anything. (i added the missing </script> tag also...)

Comment: It is working in the jsfiddle you linked, you don't see it because there are not images. Here's the code updated with working images: http://jsfiddle.net/MVnbM/2/

Comment: thanks - I see the image toggle, but not the sliding to expand/collapse the LI's

Comment: I need to show <div class="view"> at 40px height initially, then when clicking the link, expand the <div class="view"> to full height, then click again and back to 40px.

Comment: yes... but i still see the text below the hide/show image. I need this hidden until the hide/show image is clicked - it then expands to show the hidden text. sorry :(

Comment: This can be easily done, just add `overflow:hidden;` to `#view`'s definition, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MVnbM/4/

Answer (score 0):

What about this variant using `toggle` and `toggleClass`
http://jsfiddle.net/347pg/